# Mysql order all rows with null x column alphabetically by y column, then all rows without null x column alphabetically by y column

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I want to sort all rows with no value in  the x column alphabetically by column y, followed by all rows with a non null value in the x column alphabetically by column y. How can I do this?

Example

```
_x____|_y_  
null  | d  
null  | e  
null  | f  
apple | a  
peas  | b  
carrot| c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY (x IS NULL) DESC, y
```

Output:

```
|      X | Y |
|--------|---|
| (null) | d |
| (null) | e |
| (null) | f |
|  apple | a |
|   peas | b |
| carrot | c |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c6b1/2)** demo